# VSCode Gitlens Difftool show error with red underline but code is working well

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, difftool, gitlens

I just install GitLens on my VSCode. When I use difftool with old version, difftool show error with red underline. But code hasn't any problem. It work well

[image: Error Image]

Can any help me solve this problem. My file is TypeScript

**UPDATE**

Normal file is not error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQuQb.png)

Comment: it is not difftool that generates the error, it is the language tools in the editor, what is the tooltip of the error

Comment: what does the hint of the error say?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar error hint : "Cannot find module '@nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations"